# Is sum of square root and cube root always irracional?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to demostrate that $ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt[3]{y} $ is either an integer or an irrational $ \forall x,y\in \mathbb{N} $. I have simplified the problem in 4 cases:

• Both $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt[3]{y}$  are rational.

• $\sqrt{x}$ is irrational and $\sqrt[3]{y}$ rational.

• $\sqrt{x}$ is rational and $\sqrt[3]{y}$ irrational.

• Both $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt[3]{y}$  are irrational.

The only case I haven't solved yet is the last one, I have no idea what should I try.

Comment: @learning123 I think at the end you are missing some cases, because one would need to consider $x = p^k \cdot t$ with $p \not| t$ in order to be able to obtain a contradiction. But regardless of that, the case of the sum does not follow from this in any obvious way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\sqrt{x}+{y}^{1/3}=q$, where $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $y=(q-\sqrt{x})^{3}=q^3-3q^2\sqrt{x}+3qx-x\sqrt{x}\implies -y+q^3+3qx=(3q^2+x)\sqrt{x}$ or $(x+q'')\sqrt{x}=q'$, where $q', q'' \in \mathbb{Q}$ ($x$ is integer).But then this also implies that $\sqrt{x}$ is rational... Which is a contradiction.  So $\sqrt{x}+y^{1/3}$ cannot be a rational number (neither of course,  an integer) .

Comment: I can't see how this proves anything. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Proving the last statement of the OP,  @gnasher729

Comment: @gnasher729, I made some elaborations.  Do you see any flaw now?

Comment: I didn't see any flaw, but I didn't see any proof. Where does (x + 1) sqrt(x) come from?

Comment: @gnasher729, I edited the answer,  20 min ago. There is no x+1, now.

Comment: I don't get from where do you get (x+q")sqrt(x)=q'

Comment: Sorry for the delay but it difficult to write with a smartphone.  Is it clear now?@DanielSánchezPagán